# Cannot load Stripe over http in Safari 9

Tags: https, stripe-payments

Trying to load Stripe.js over http results in this error:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost.dev:8080" 
from accessing a frame with origin "https://js.stripe.com".  
The frame requesting access has a protocol of "about", 
the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". 
Protocols must match.
```

Simplest script possible:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/">   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This does not occur in Chrome/FF - only Safari 9. Is this a known issue/change and is there a workaround? And what is this 'about' thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It was LiveReload server running that caused interference. Leaving question up in case it helps.