# Stripe.js and AngularJS - Loading Stripe library fails

Tags: angularjs, stripe-payments

i am trying to integrate Stripe into my web application (Frontend is AngularJS). When i am developing i am on localhost:9000, but when i try to load Stripe.js with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

i get an error:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9000" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "https://js.stripe.com".  The frame requesting
>   access has a protocol of "about", the frame being accessed has a
>   protocol of http

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What's the URL of the page you're developing on?

Comment: its on localhost (development mode)

Comment: Are you using live reload?

Comment: yes livereload is on

Comment: Try it without live reload. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491222/cannot-load-stripe-over-http-in-safari-9 indicates there may be a conflict there.

Comment: thanks a lot it was exactly that!

Comment: Awesome, glad that helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the livereload from Gruntfile.js solved the issue in Safari.
Just comment out livereload:

```
//livereload: 35729
```